# Equivalent of ChannelSink for upstream events

Tags: java, netty

I have an upstream Netty pipeline built where one of the early upstream handler (we will call it CometDecoder) in the pipeline must send an empty long poll request to its corresponding CometEncoder on the downstream side if and only if the remaining upstream handlers do not send a substantive request downstream through the CometEncoder in response to the received request.

[image]

The reason is that this legacy server expects a long polling request to always be open, and not every response from the server provokes a subsequent request from the client.

There seems to be a ChannelSink in Netty that is used as a terminal downstream handler in the pipeline.  It would be great if there was a similar construct that would allow us to hook into a terminal UPSTREAM handler and check the state of whether or not a message has been sent by one of the intermediate upstream handlers.  Is there such a thing in Netty?

Any other approaches found by folks that have had to deal with Comet programming in Netty?

Comment: I may not get your use case completly but why not just have a Handler that extends SimpleChannelHandler and keeps state of everything ?

Comment: In this case, because the UpstreamHandlers upstream of CometDecoder are dynamically added and removed (each is associated with a different service).  Such a Handler would have to always be last.  I could subclass Pipeline and overload the add..() methods, but it just seems a bit hokey.